# ¿Puedo hacer que al pulsar un botón se ejecute un shortcode o un action? WordPress

Tags: php, html, wordpress, botón

Tengo un shortcode que me lee los datos de un formulario (tipo usuario y contraseña) y si están en la base de datos, me muestra los datos de ese usuario.

Quiero actualizar los datos de eses usuario, para hacerlo tengo otro shortcode que me debería actualizar los datos, el problema es que el shortcode que me comprueba si los datos (de usuario y contraseña) están bien, me genera el formulario donde aparecen los datos del usuario (por si los quiere modificar) y claro no se como hacer que al usuario darle al botón de modificar, se ejecute el shortcode que tengo para modificar los datos.

Shortcode que comprueba y genera los datos a modificar (usuario = NumTarjetaFidelizacion y contraseña = ClaveTarjeta):

```
add_shortcode('compDatos', 'comprobarDatos');
function comprobarDatos(){
$NumTarjetaFidelizacion = $_POST['NumTarjetaFidelizacion'];
$ClaveTarjeta = $_POST['ClaveTarjeta'];
global $wpdb;
$datos = $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM nikkiclub WHERE numerotarjeta='$NumTarjetaFidelizacion' AND Clavetarjeta='$ClaveTarjeta'" ));
$mostrarDatos='
<div><h3>Datos del primer titular</h3></div>
<form method="post">
<div>Nombre: <input type="text" name="nombretutor1" value=' .$datos[0]->nombretutor1. '> Apellidos: <input type="text" name="apellidostutor1" value=' .$datos[0]->apellidostutor1. '>DNI: <input type="text" name="dnitutor1" value=' .$datos[0]->dnitutor1. '></div>
<input type="submit" value="Modificar" >
</form>';
return $mostrarDatos;
```

}

Comment: Creo que ayer estuve comentando sobre esto de los shortcode y los hooks contigo, me alegro de que te hayas lanzado con ellos :) En lo que planteas aquí te propondría que eches mano de Ajax. Así, en vez de llamar a otro short code, puedes implementar en esa misma página la posibilidad de actualizar, mandando la actualización vía Ajax. Va a ser una combinación interesante si aprendes a usarlo. Ten en cuenta que, al estar del lado de PHP en esta función, ya no tienes por qué volver al entorno de Wordpress para actualizar, es mejor hacerlo desde ahí, no sé si me explico...

Comment: Otra cosa que debo advertirte es que tengas cuidado con esta consulta: `$datos = $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM nikkiclub WHERE numerotarjeta='$NumTarjetaFidelizacion' AND Clavetarjeta='$ClaveTarjeta'" ));`, no es realmente una consulta preparada, aunque uses `prepare`, porque estás pasando los datos en la misma consulta y puedes sufrir ataques de inyección SQL. Mira [en este enlace](https://www.lingulo.com/quick-tips/wordpress-database-queries-how-to-do-with-prepare) ejemplos de consultas preparadas desde Wordpress, implementa las consultas así para darles seguridad.

Comment: hola, si ayer estuvimos hablando del tema de los shortcodes y me sirvió bastante, después de echar un vistazo sobre como crearlos bien y demás he visto que son muy útiles la verdad

Comment: ahora he visto en una publicación que si le añado en la funcion del shortcode un if (isset($_POST['boton']))
Puedo hacer que me ejecute ese código al darle al botón
Pero no se si sera lo mas indicado y la verdad tengo ganas de aprender un poco ajax he visto también que es muy util.

Comment: Dado que el shortcode por decirlo de alguna forma, te mete de lleno en el terreno de PHP, si ahora quieres actualizar no tienes necesidad de volver al terreno de Wordpress a implementar otro shortcode para actualizar. Desde ahí mismo le puedes poner al formulario por ejemplo un botón `Actualizar` y escuchar vía Javascript si ese botón fue pulsado y lanzar mediante Ajax una actualización a la base de datos, recogiendo del mismo formulario los datos que necesites como el `id` u otros. O sea, estando ya en ese terreno no necesitas otro shortcode. El shortcode es para desde un post pasar a PHP.

Comment: Vale vale, bueno pues me toca mirar ajax a ver como se hace lo que dices, entiendo (desde mi infinita ignorancia) que en el shortcode que tengo que me muestra los datos generando los en un formulario, en ese shortcode añadir la escucha de javaScript para que cuando se le de al botón se me ejecute el ajax? vamos que el codigo de ajax y javascript se ejecuten desde el botón.

Comment: Exacto. Javascript y Ajax están del lado del cliente, así como el formulario (o sea, todo eso está en el HTML que se muestra al cliente). Si al botón de actualizar le das un `id="btnActualizar"` puedes *escuchar*  desde Javascript cuando el usuario hace click en ese botón y a partir de ahí lanzar una petición al servidor vía Ajax. Esa es la magia de Ajax, que te comunica entre cliente y servidor además sin necesidad de recargar la página, de modo que le puedes enviar datos al servidor para que actualice, inserte, modifique, etc. Pero pon atención a lo que te dije de la inyección SQL.

Comment: si si ya me abri el enlace que me mandaste respecto a la inyeccion sql y en cuanto tenga lo de ajax funcionando ya me pongo a ello muchas gracias compañero por la ayuda.

Comment: sabes de algún buen tutorial de como usar ajax en wordpress por que los que he visto no me entero muy bien la verdad